# My textures are not being applied to the mesh I am editing inside the Shader Editor

Tags: texturing, uv, export, .fbx, unreal-engine

Context:

I bought [this](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/animal-pack-ultra-01) animal pack that I want to use inside of Twinmotion and maybe Sketchup.
Thus I look for ways to export the .fbx file **with** textures. I find [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDz7X2RZDvM&t=510s) tutorial on the matter which requires the use of blender. No worries, I'll follow all the steps.

But whereas he **instantly** gets a result while adding the textures (the viewport is updated automatically), I get nothing. I add the color file in both TGA and PNG versions and neither changes anything: my cow mesh is still metallic grey.

Here are some usefull screenshots of my blender workspace and also the texture files that I exported from Unreal Engine along with the mesh.

[image: View of my shader editor window]

[image: View of my mesh]

All the textures can be accessed via [this Ufile.io link](https://ufile.io/f/686sh).

[image: Preview of the color texture]

I'm thankfull for any tips anyone might have on this issue, I honestly did not imagine the usage of a pre-existing 3D cow would prove so complicated...

Comment: You can preview materials by changing the Viewport Shading mode to 'Material Preview'. Either press 'z' and then '2' or use the sphere icons on the top right of the viewport.

Comment: Omg, I knew it was going to be such a 2 click fix, it works!
This is why forums like this are so usefull, I would have had to read 50 pages of documentation before trying this and finding the solution...

Thank you!